# Customer Selenium webdriver java method for validating table search results

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am wanting to create a custom method in a Base page object that will allow me to validate the results returned in a dynamic table after searching.

I have the below method ..

It takes as arguments the WebElement table, a column name that I want to validate against and and expected value that I expect to be returned by a row of that column.

I am trying to find the column index of the column with name that I pass in as columnName and assign it to a variable called searchedColIndex then use this to get all values returned under that column and then validate whether the expected result was in the list.

However I am not sure how to get the index of the column.

Also I never seem to get inside the if statement, even though when I print both column.getText() and columnName to console the values are correct and should match for one of columns, but that if statement is never evaluated as true.

```
public void validateTableData2(WebElement table,String columnName, String expectedSearchResult){
    List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr"));
    List<WebElement> tableColumns = table.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
    int searchedColIndex = 1;
    for (WebElement column : tableColumns) {
        if(column.getText().trim() == columnName.trim()){
            System.out.println("We don't get in this if statement");
            System.out.println("The values in column headers are available as if I print column.getText() then it does return correct column headings");
            //Not sure how I can assign the index of the column I am interested in
            //column.getText() does 
        }
    }
    List<String> returnedVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 1; i < tableRows.size(); i++) {
        String returnedVal = table.findElement(By.xpath("./tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+searchedColIndex+"]")).getText();
        returnedVals.add(returnedVal);
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(returnedVals.contains(expectedSearchResult));
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am wondering if I could use the preceding-sibling attribute to get count of pre-ceding siblings and use this as the index. But not sure how I can assign this to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with the below method, which seems to work, although perhaps won't work for every table I try to use it with ..

```
public void validateTableData2(WebElement table,String columnName, String expectedSearchResult){
    List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr"));
    System.out.println("Col name is " +columnName);
    int searchedColIndex = table.findElements(By.xpath("//thead/tr/th/a[text()='"+columnName+"']/../preceding-sibling::th")).size()+1;
    List<String> returnedVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 1; i < tableRows.size(); i++) {
        String returnedVal = table.findElement(By.xpath("./tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+searchedColIndex+"]")).getText();
        System.out.println("Returned val is "+returnedVal);
        returnedVals.add(returnedVal);
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(returnedVals.contains(expectedSearchResult));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, use equals() instead of ==, then you should get inside the if statement.